# He said that he was not feeling well, so I suggested him {to see a doctor/that he should see a doctor}

Tags: sentence-construction

How should the sentence end?

> He said that he was not feeling well, so I suggested him **to see a doctor**.
>
> He said that he was not feeling well, so I suggested him **that he should see a doctor**.

Are both correct usage? If so, then which one is better?

Answer (score 3):

> He said that he was not feeling well, so I suggested **to** him **that he should see a doctor**.

Or you could make the sentence shorter because the "to him" is implied:

> He said that he was not feeling well, so I suggested he see a doctor.

Comment: Why is "He said that he was not feeling well, so I suggested him to see a doctor" incorrect?

Comment: My first answer is that "him" is not the _direct object_ of the sentence.  The suggestion (that he should see a doctor) is the direct object.  However as I think more about it I wonder why it is ok to say "I sent him a letter" and "I gave him a car".   So I looked up "send" and "suggest" in some dictionaries and all I can say is that according to the examples at Oxford English Dictionary "[send](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/send)" can have two objects while "[suggest](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/suggest)" only has one

Comment: Actually, the best answer I can give is that I'm a native speaker and "I suggested to him" just sounds wrong.